# How to call emergency meeting on the Submerged map?

Tags: among-us

Unlike on other maps, pressing the Emergency Meeting button in the meeting room on the [Submerged map](https://among-us.fandom.com/wiki/Mod:Submerged) shows a message "Waiting for host" in the box below the button, and no meeting is called. Is there something that needs to be done to enable the emergency meeting, or is it a bug, or a missing/incomplete feature?
Searching on Google yielded nothing of substance, and none of the videos about the new map I found seem to mention calling emergency meetings.

Comment: Is that a modded map? Dont see any reference to a new map after the airship on the wiki. There is one in development, but nothing more has been announced. If its a mod, I guess there could be a glitch.

Comment: @Fredy31 Yes, it's a mod, a very complex, entirely new map with a range of new tasks and a bunch of new mechanics - [Submerged](https://among-us.fandom.com/wiki/Mod:Submerged).  [Trailer video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAX_mDOX4Pc)

Comment: Yeah, so I guess my general knowledge of Among Us doesn't apply. But since its a pretty big mod and its not mentionned in the wiki page (even tho its incomplete) I guess there is a glitch that you are experiencing.

Comment: @Fredy31 Yeah, that map has some quite unique mechanics. For example, O2 sabotage requires all on board (crewmates and impostors alike) to acquire oxygen masks before the time expires; anyone without a mask dies when the countdown ends. Lights sabotage results in lights blinking for a while, followed by a moment of total darkness, which only then turns to the familiar small circle of light around the player. There are cameras scattered throughout the ship you must fix to use later. Whether the button is broken as a bug or as intended mechanics - the mod is polished enough all bets are off.